# store MySQL column values in different variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've a table with few fields 
Table _name : **ferrari**

```
 id | name |          

|  2 | Ferrari       

|  3 | red Ferrari    

|  5 | silver Ferrari 

|  7 | pink Ferrari
```

Here I need to fetch name from table ferrari and store into different variables in PHP.. Table rows will be unlimited. I've used loops..But doesn't work.Please help..

ie

```
<?php
$a = "red Ferrari";
$b = "silver Ferrari";
$c = "pink Ferrari";
?>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Show what you have actually tried please.

Comment: "Doesn't work" could be a lot of things. Show the code you are having problems with. Explain what *exactly* doesn't work - does it crash? Blank screen? Does something but not what you want? Also, you need to access your error logs. What do they state?

Comment: You're questions is irrelevant, please search before you type any question

Comment: @Anas but we need to educate *why* it's pointless so they post better Qs in the future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, Your all database column records contain in variable like below

```html
$db_column_array = array('Ferrari','Silver Ferrari','Red Ferrari');
```

Now Used the for loop, to create multiple variable

```html
for($i=0;$i<=count($db_column_array);$i++)
    {
        ${"variable".$i} = $db_column_array[$i];                                          
    }
```

Now, Your multiple variable has been created

```html
$variable0 = 'Ferrari';
$variable1 = 'Silver Ferrari';
$variable2 = 'Red Ferrari';
```